# Google Drive read partial file in python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have an App Engine site and I want to get the last 300 bytes from a file in Google Drive.I tried using the HTTP Range header with Python's urllib2 as follows:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (-300, 2)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
# This shows you the *actual* bytes that have been downloaded.
range=f.headers.get('Content-Range')
logging.info("range:"+range)
logging.info("read:"+(f.read()))
```

The url is actually the 'downloadurl' attribute from the file metadata.I get this error when I run it

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Is it possible that the Range header isn't accepted?I really do not want to download the entire file.Anyone with a solution?

EDIT

Thanks to @Claudio Cherubino for this answer!

```
creds = GetSessionCredentials() //from Google Python Client API
size = int('size of my file')
headers = {"Range" : 'bytes=%s-%s' % (size-300, size)} //Range Header
http = httplib2.Http()
http = creds.authorize(http) //add OAuth credentials
resp, content = http.request(url, "GET", body=None, headers=headers)
if resp.status == 206:
   print 'Status: %s' % resp
   print "content:"+content
else:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % resp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an OAuth token to your request as explained in the docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials